What is Microsoft's recommended way to access OneDriveAPI from mobile devices?
I am building a .NET MAUI application that will mainly run on iOS, but it should be possible to run it on Android devices later. I need to create folders and files in OneDrive, after some research I found out that I need to implement the GraphServiceClient to access OneDrive. I looked for a way to let the user sign in. In the Microsoft documentation you have to choose an approach, I chose the Interactive Provider which is recommended for mobile apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#interactive-provider
But I run into the following error that the platform is not supported:
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: Operation is not supported on this platform." ... -> this happens in the line: interactiveCredential.Authenticate(new TokenRequestContext(scopes));
May I also add, that it works on windows without any issues. This is the code I implemented so far:
        string redirectUri = "http://localhost"; #if ANDROID || IOS redirectUri = $"msal{clientId}://auth"; #endif

        var tokenCacheOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions
        {
            Name = "msal_cache",
            UnsafeAllowUnencryptedStorage = false
        };
        var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = "common",
            ClientId = clientId,
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            RedirectUri = new Uri(redirectUri),
            TokenCachePersistenceOptions = tokenCacheOptions
        };
        InteractiveBrowserCredential interactiveCredential;
        if (File.Exists(_authRecordPath)) //Check if token already exists in cache
        {
            var authRecordJson = File.ReadAllText(_authRecordPath);
            AuthenticationRecord authRecord;
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(_authRecordPath))
            {
                authRecord = AuthenticationRecord.Deserialize(stream);
            }
            
            options.AuthenticationRecord = authRecord;
            interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
            UserLoggedIn = true;
        }
        else //promp login
        {
            interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
            var authRecord = interactiveCredential.Authenticate(new TokenRequestContext(scopes));
            using (var stream = File.Create(_authRecordPath))
            {
                authRecord.Serialize(stream);
            }
            UserLoggedIn = true;
        }

        _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

